Composing sums of elements in $\pi_{n}(S^m)$
Suppose $m,n,r\geq 1$ and that we have homotopy group elements $f,g\in \pi_{n}(S^m)$ and $\alpha,\beta\in \pi_r(S^n)$. Certainly, it is the case that $f\circ (\alpha+\beta)=(f\circ\alpha)+(f\circ\beta)$. I expect the relation $(f+g)\circ \alpha=(f\circ\alpha)+(g\circ\alpha)$ is probably false in general or it'd be prominently featured in basic textbooks (and I haven't seen it). However, it is obviously true in the very special case $m=n=r$ and (less obviously) perhaps always in the stable range if I understand correctly.
What is a counterexample to the relation $(f+g)\circ \alpha=(f\circ\alpha)+(g\circ\alpha)$ or did I miss this relation being proved somewhere?

This is a very classical question in homotopy theory. Let us more generally consider the composition product $\circ\colon\pi_n(X)\times\pi_r(S^n)\rightarrow\pi_r(X)$. The composition product is always a homomorphism in the second variable. It is indeed typically not a homomorphism in the first variable. The easy sufficient conditions are that $X$ is an $H$-space (in the case that $X=S^m$ is a sphere, this is only satisfied for $m=1,3,7$) or that we fix a co-$H$-map in the second variable. In particular, the relation holds after suspending once (because suspensions are co-$H$-maps), so there are no complications stably.
Now, to talk about addition more conceptually, consider the universal example given by the maps $j_1,j_2\colon S^n\rightarrow S^n\vee S^n$. For $\alpha\in\pi_r(S^n)$, we obtain a "difference element"
$$(j_1+j_2)\circ\alpha-j_1\circ\alpha-j_2\circ\alpha\in\pi_r(S^n\vee S^n).$$
The projection to each summand is trivial, so this is canonically an element $H(\alpha)\in\pi_{r+1}(S^n\times S^n,S^n\vee S^n)$, called the generalized Hopf invariant. [Here, recall that the LES of the pair $(S^n\times S^n,S^n\vee S^n)$ canonically splits into short exact sequences.] It now is immediate by naturality that for $f,g\in\pi_n(X)$, we have
$$(f+g)\circ\alpha=f\circ\alpha+g\circ\alpha+(f\vee g)_{\ast}(\partial H(\alpha)).$$
Thus, the element $H(\alpha)$ measures the failure of $-\circ\alpha$ to be a homomorphism (more precisely, $H(\alpha)=0$ if and only if $\alpha$ is a co-$H$-map). Note that this yields a homomorphism $H\colon\pi_r(S^n)\rightarrow\pi_{r+1}(S^n\times S^n,S^n\vee S^n)$.
This is neat, but of course the element $H(\alpha)\in\pi_{r+1}(S^n\times S^n,S^n\vee S^n)$ is still quite mysterious. Assume $n\ge2$ (the case $n=1$ can be done by hand). Now, we can use the pair LES, the Hurewicz theorem and Künneth theorem to deduce that $(S^n\times S^n,S^n\vee S^n)$ is $(2n-1)$-connected and its first non-trivial homotopy group is described by the cross product isomorphism
$$\times\colon\pi_n(S^n)\otimes\pi_n(S^n)\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}\pi_{2n}(S^n\times S^n,S^n\vee S^n).$$
In particular, $H(\alpha)=0$ if $r\le2n-2$ and then the relation always holds. This also recovers your $r=n$ case. This could have alternatively been obtained by Freudenthal suspension. In the case $r=2n-1$, the group in question is $\mathbb{Z}$, so we obtain a homomorphism $H\colon\pi_{2n-1}(S^n)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying
$$(f+g)\circ\alpha=f\circ\alpha+g\circ\alpha+H(\alpha)[f,g],\qquad\forall f,g\in\pi_n(X).$$
The element $[f,g]\in\pi_{2n-1}(X)$ here is the Whitehead product. It turns out that this homomorphism $H$ is the usual Hopf invariant, as the name suggests. This is elementary, but non-trivial, for it requires us to relate a homotopical to a cohomological invariant. The cohomological description implies $H=0$ if $n$ is odd, yielding another class of examples where the relation holds. More importantly, however, it also yields counter-examples: Take $f=g=\iota_n$, the identity of $S^n$, for some even $n$. Then, $(2\iota_n)\circ\alpha=2(\iota_n\circ\alpha)+H(\alpha)[\iota_n,\iota_n]$. The element $[\iota_n,\iota_n]$ is non-torsion (the topical way of seeing this is to calculate that this map itself has Hopf invariant $2$), so it suffices to take $\alpha$ to be your favorite map with non-zero Hopf invariant, perhaps the Hopf fibration $S^3\rightarrow S^2$.
For $r>2n-1$, life becomes significantly harder. There is a general method of decomposing $\pi_{r+1}(S^n\times S^n,S^n\vee S^1n)$ as a direct sum of homotopy groups of spheres,  which yields a sum decomposition of the generalized Hopf invariant in terms of iterated Whitehead products and the so-called Hopf-Hilton invariants, the first of which is the usual Hopf invariant. The combinatorics involved, however, are really complicated and I won't pretend I understand them. The classical textbook reference for everything I've said and more is George W. Whitehead, Elements of Homotopy Theory, Chapters $X$ and $XI$. [Historical Note: It was this very George W. Whitehead who introduced (a version of) the Generalized Hopf Invariant in 1950 and then used it to give the first correct calculation of the $2$nd stable stem.]

Wonderful answer! This should be accepted. Ignorant readers like myself should complement with a read of Whitehead products and Hopf invariants, that are interesting concepts on their own

Yes, a fantastic and thoughtful answer for many reasons. Thank you!
